# desktop launcher for sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade

Tags: launcher

I have Kubuntu 18.04. How can I create a desktop launcher for the code:

```
sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: It is bad idea to have shortcut for interactive terminal application. Using Muon or Discover would be better, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Create a text file and call it `updateme.desktop`. Paste the following and save it:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=update system
Comment=updates system
Exec=bash -c 'sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y; bash'
Terminal=true
Type=Application
```

Now run `chmod +x /path/to/updateme.desktop`

Double clicking on the file should now bring up a terminal asking for your password to execute the commands. If you want you can copy it to `/usr/share/applications` to make it appear in your application's menu.

Thanks to @Terrance for having corrected the Exec command.

Comment: Add "sudo" also to the upgrade command, and you are in business.

Comment: No, you are still not there: I tried with only the update command, and then it works fine. It however does not work with two connected commands: after typing the sudo password, the terminal vanishes.

Comment: Hmm, that's strange, I'll see if I can implement it better, but it's really late here so I think I'll have to follow up tomorrow, sorry :/

Comment: Change the `Exec=` to `Exec=bash -c 'sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y; bash'`  I only added the `; bash` at the end to keep the terminal open.  It can be removed if you want.

Comment: `Exec=Exec=bash` looks a bit weird to me...